# Is there a way to add To-Do's to iCal from the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ical

Is there a way to add To-Do's to iCal from the iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With iOS5 and iCloud, iCal's reminders appear in the Reminders app.

Comment: Works like a charm. Make a new reminder with the Reminder app and it shows up in iCal on the Mac immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Not until Apple decides to release this feature.
There are tons of 3rd party applications that sport some kind of To-do list, some can even sync with your iCal.

I don't use To-do's on my phone so I can't name any alternative apps.